# How to get the Value of an Object by using Value of Array as Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array which holds multiple values.
I also have an object which contains data.

Now I want to create an object which only holds the the data which has the same key as the value of the array.

```
const array = ["foo", "bar", "foo2", "bar2"]
var obj = {foo:"string1", fue:"string2", bar:"string3"
```

The Object I want to create should look like this:

```
var result = {foo:"string1", bar:"string3"}
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: They are strings. Just corrected the sniped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the object keys and see if they exist in array using `Array.prototype.includes` and add the values in a result object

```js
const array = ["foo", "bar", "foo2", "bar2"]
var obj = {foo:"string1", fue:"string2", bar:"string3"}
var result = {};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
   if(array.includes(key)) {
        result[key] = obj[key];
   }
})

console.log(result)
```

Also as @Jacob pointed out, it would be more efficient if you loop over the array and pick keys from the object  if they exist as accesing keys from object is O(1) operation whereas checking in array is an O(n) operation

```js
const array = ["foo", "bar", "foo2", "bar2"]
var obj = {foo:"string1", fue:"string2", bar:"string3"}
var result = {};
array.forEach(key => {
   if(obj[key]) {
        result[key] = obj[key];
   }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Pretty minor impact for small arrays, but this means multiple iterations over `array` for each object key. My approach iterates over the array instead. Haven't measured performance differences.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. It works!
I´m using this in my vue instance. For some reason I don´t get the right keys in my Object. I use it as a computed.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach:

```
const obj = { foo:"string1", fue:"string2", bar:"string3" };

const subset = pick(obj, ["foo", "bar", "foo2", "bar2"]);

function pick(obj, props) {
  return props.reduce((result, prop) => {
    return (prop in obj) ? Object.assign(result, { [prop]: obj[prop] }) : result;
  }, {});
}
```

(If you are already using lodash, there's a `_.pick` method that does this).